# How to change image on clicking existing image in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a button within tableViewcell  with Image contained in it. I want to get option to change the image on tapping the previous image(which is a button),like opening gallery or camera.I am using following code to implement this:
In tableView cell:

```
protocol Profile2 : class{
    func OnClick_2(index : Int)
}
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   weak var celldelegate : Profile2?
    var index : IndexPath?
  }
```

In View Controller

```
   @IBAction func changeProfileImage(_ sender: Any) {
 let action_sheet = UIAlertController(title: "Click to choose photo", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
               
               
               
               action_sheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                   self.ShowAlbum()
               }))
               action_sheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        }
//Show album method
func ShowAlbum()
       {
           let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
           imagePicker.delegate = self
           imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
           present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
       }
//In cell for row method:
  cell.celldelegate = self
            cell.index = indexPath
            cell.profilePicture.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
//imagepicker method
   func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
           self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in

           })
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "profilePictureCell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.profilePicture.imageView?.image = image
        
       }
```

on tapping the button actionsheet is opened for uploading image from gallery but on selecting image and uploading it is not getting set into the button.
Please suggest me how to solve it or do it in alternative way.

Comment: Tapping an image view doesn't do anything. You have to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it in your cell class, and then call your delegate function from there. Start with searching for `swift tap on uiimageview`. Then implement that in your cell class. Then implement the delegate function.

Comment: @DonMag First of all, its not an UIImageView to put an UITapGestureRecognizer on it. He's trying to change the image which is set on a button.

Comment: @Suhail - whoops... I was focused on the post title.

Comment: *Fixing my first comment...* You need to implement your button tap action in your cell class, assign the delegate in your controller's `cellForRowAt`, and the call the delegate function from the action method in your cell.

Comment: @DonMag on tapping the button actionsheet is opened for uploading image from gallery but on choosing image and uploading it is not getting set into the button.can you please suggest me how to resolve it?

Comment: @satyamkumar - if you're still looking for help on this, you need to provide more information. Do you have a "profile picture" and a button in each cell? And you want to change the image in that cell when tapping the button? Or, do you have *one* cell with a profile picture, and your "select image" button is somwhere else (such as in the navigation bar)? Do you have a datasource / structure that is used to set the initial image when the cell is first displayed? etc...